# Is it possible to disable a port using docker command

Tags: docker

I would like to test the case where a micro-service port might be down or blocked by firewall

- I would like to simulate this by disable the 9001:9001 binding, is this possible via docker, using a docker command? Or does the port binding only possible at runtime
- If this is not possible is there a unix command to disable a port temporarily or remove a firewall rule?

Comment: I am not quite sure what the purpose of this is. If the firewall is misconfigured, fix it. If the firewall is maintained by a 3rd party, inform them. If you want to simulate service failure, use tools like [chaos monkey](https://github.com/Netflix/chaosmonkey). Configure the monitoring accordingly to trigger an alarm when the service is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

On your host machine, the firewall should be available, which you can use the docker containers ip or subnet, and then you can assign a port to allow or block. For example ubuntu uses UFW,

To allow the IP address or subnet 15.15.15.0/24 to port 22
`sudo ufw allow from 15.15.15.0/24  to any port 22`

To allow MySQL connections to the eth1 interface, docker has its own interface by default, and you can create your own interface also using docker, for docker containers,
`sudo ufw allow in on eth1 to any port 3306`